# What is a context register in golang?

Tags: go, compilation

What is a ***context register*** and how does it change the way Go code is compiled?

*Context:* I've seen uses of stub functions in some parts of GOROOT, i.e. `reflect`, but am not quite sure how these work.

Comment: A "context register" is just what the Go authors called the register holding the context for a closure. Stub functions (which are implemented non-locally, like in assembly files, the runtime, etc) aren't really related. And yes, if you have questions on this the mailing list is a much more appropriate forum.

Comment: Hopefully this isn't too meta, but why is stackoverflow -- a site whose entire purpose is literally asking and answering questions about programming -- somehow "much less appropriate" for a go-lang question than an email list?

Comment: @eje: The best reason is that if you want an answer about an implementation detail in the gc toolchain the mailing list is a better forum, simply because the developers are active there, and much less so here. This assumes the OP did due diligence and has already looked at the commit log (which VonC quoted for us below), and wants more context which the original developers could provide.

Answer (score 7):

The expression "context register" first appeared in [commit b1b67a3](https://github.com/golang/go/commit/b1b67a36ace635744cd261ee6f3441d1044c66b3) (Feb. 2013, Go 1.1rc2) for implementing step 3 of the [Go 1.1 Function Calls](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1bMwCey-gmqZVTpRax-ESeVuZGmjwbocYs1iHplK-cjo/pub)

> Change the `reflect.MakeFunc` implementation to avoid run-time code generation as well

It was picked up in [commit 4a000b9](https://github.com/golang/go/commit/4a000b9d51b88346e01464f2cf8b8ab7eaa66063) in Feb. 2014, Go 1.3beta1, for assembly and system calls for Native Client x86-64, where [sigreturn is managed as](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/4a000b9d51b88346e01464f2cf8b8ab7eaa66063/src/pkg/runtime/sys_nacl_386.s#L189-L217):

> `NaCl` has abidcated its traditional operating system responsibility and declined to implement '`sigreturn`'.
>   Instead the only way to return to the execution of our program is to restore the registers ourselves.
>
> Unfortunately, that is impossible to do with strict fidelity, because there is no way to do the final update of PC that ends the sequence without either
>
> - (1) jumping to a register, in which case the register ends holding the PC value instead of its intended value, or
> - (2) storing the `PC` on the stack and using `RET`, which imposes the requirement that `SP` is valid and that is okay to smash the word below it.
>
> The second would normally be the lesser of the two evils, except that on NaCl, the linker must rewrite `RET` into "`POP reg; AND $~31, reg; JMP reg`", so either way we are going to lose a register as a result of the incoming signal.
>
> Similarly, there is no way to restore `EFLAGS`; the usual way is to use `POPFL`, but `NaCl` rejects that instruction.
>   We could inspect the bits and execute a sequence of instructions designed to recreate those flag settings, but that's a lot of work.
>
> Thankfully, Go's signal handlers never try to return directly to the executing code, so all the registers and `EFLAGS` are dead and can be smashed.
>   The only registers that matter are the ones that are setting up for the simulated call that the signal handler has created.
>   Today those registers are just `PC` and `SP`, but in case additional registers are relevant in the future (**for example `DX` is the Go func `context register`**) we restore as many registers as possible.

Much more recently (Q4 2016), for Go 1.8, we have [commit d5bd797](https://github.com/golang/go/commit/d5bd797ee55d36b07b388d0b8ca2393dc186bea1) and [commit bf9c71c](https://github.com/golang/go/commit/bf9c71cb434a730679f54a3a87c2e9e36ec400d0), for [eliminating stack rescanning](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/17503):

> `morestack` writes the context pointer to `gobuf.ctxt`, but since
>   `morestack` is written in assembly (and has to be very careful with
>   state), it does *not* invoke the requisite write barrier for this
>   write. Instead, we patch this up later, in `newstack`, where we invoke
>   an explicit write barrier for ctxt.
>
> This already requires some subtle reasoning, and it's going to get a
>   lot hairier with the hybrid barrier.
>
> Fix this by simplifying the whole mechanism.
>   Instead of writing `gobuf.ctxt` in `morestack`, **just pass the value of the context register to `newstack` and let it write it to `gobuf.ctxt`**. This is a normal Go pointer write, so it gets the normal Go write barrier. No subtle reasoning required.